# Prompt system from reading a text file

Tags: java, file, console, io

I worked starting from basic example code from an exercise in chapter 10 of [Java: A Beginner's Guide, Sixth Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071809252), the code in the exercise was not very good and I wanted to improve upon it and make it my own, so this is what I came up with.

This reads the content of a text file, displays and reads titles/subjects, which lines are preceded by the `#` character, gets text input from the console, and displays information from searching the text file again for the user-input search.

I realize it's probably not very good, and I'm looking to improve my handling of I/O in general, please critique it thoroughly.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Help System using a text file as source.
 */
public class HelpSystem {
    private char titleLineMarker;
    private final String STOP_WORD = "stop";
    private final String HELP_SYSTEM_FILE_PATH = "C:/git/JavaExercises/src/chapter10/HelpSystem.txt";

    /**
     * Default constructor assumes character '#' is assumed to be the
     * line marker for titles/headers, according to standard Markdown syntax.
     */
    public HelpSystem() {
        titleLineMarker = '#';
        run();
    }

    /**
     * Alternate constructor with different line marker.
     * @param titleLineMarker the marker character that marks a line as subtitle.
     */
    public HelpSystem(char titleLineMarker) {
        this.titleLineMarker = titleLineMarker;
        run();
    }

    /**
     * Run the HelpSystem app.
     */
    private void run() {
        String topic;
        System.out.printf("Try the help system. Enter \"%s\" to end.", STOP_WORD);
        readTopics();
        do {
            topic = getSelection();
            if (!isStop(topic)) {
                if (!helpOn(topic)) {
                    System.out.printf("Topic not found: %s%n", topic);
                }
            }
        } while(!isStop(topic));
    }

    /**
     * Reads the help topics based on the character provided as a marker for lines containing a header.
     */
    private void readTopics() {
        System.out.println("Topics:");
        try(BufferedReader topicReader = new BufferedReader((new FileReader(HELP_SYSTEM_FILE_PATH)))) {
            int cursor;
            final char NOTHING = '\0';
            do {
                cursor = topicReader.read();
                if(cursor == titleLineMarker) {
                    System.out.println(" - " + topicReader.readLine().replace(titleLineMarker, NOTHING));
                }
            } while(cursor != -1);
        } catch(IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Search for a help topic entered by user.
     * @param what the help topic to search for
     * @return whether the topic is found
     */
    private boolean helpOn(String what) {
        int ch;
        String topic;
        String info;
        try (BufferedReader helpReader = new BufferedReader((new FileReader(HELP_SYSTEM_FILE_PATH)))) {
            do {
                ch = helpReader.read();
                if(ch == titleLineMarker) {
                    topic = helpReader.readLine();
                    if(what.compareTo(topic) == 0) { // found topic
                        do {
                            info = helpReader.readLine();
                            if(info != null && info.compareTo("") != 0) {
                                System.out.println(info);
                            }
                        } while(info != null && info.compareTo("") != 0);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } while(ch != -1);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        // topic not found:
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to find whether the topic the user entered exists.
     * @return whether the topic the user entered exists
     */
    private String getSelection() {
        String topic = "";
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter topic: ");
        try {
            topic = inputReader.readLine();
        } catch(IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        return topic;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the input matches the stop word.
     * @param input the input to search for
     * @return whether the input matches the stop word
     */
    private boolean isStop(String input) {
        return input.toLowerCase().equals(STOP_WORD);
    }
    // Test the class:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelpSystem help = new HelpSystem();
    }
}
```

FYI, this is what it looks like when ran:

> ```
> Try the help system. Enter "stop" to end.Topics:
>  - if
>  - while
> Enter topic: if
> if (condition) {
>     // if statements
> } else {
>     // else statements
> }
> Enter topic: foo
> Topic not found: foo
> Enter topic: stop
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

Based on text file `HelpSystem.txt` below - obviously could have more useful content, but this will do for now.

> ```
> #if
> if (condition) {
>     // if statements
> } else {
>     // else statements
> }
>
> #while
> while (condition) {
>     // statements
> }
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Interface

I don't think that instantiating a `HelpSystem` should have a side-effect of starting the interpreter loop.  Either of these following designs would be better:

- Instantiate, then run the loop separately

  ```
    HelpSystem help = new HelpSystem();
    help.run();
  ```
- A static method

  ```
    HelpSystem.run();
  ```

It would be better for the no-argument constructor to chain to `this('#');` instead of setting `titleLineMarker` itself.  But why should the marker be configurable at all?  Just settle on the file format an stick to it.

Note that anytime you have a special character, you should probably also have a mechanism for allowing that character to be treated literally.  See [RFC 821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) Section 4.5.2 for an example of such an escaping mechanism.

Better yet, avoid inventing your own format, and use a standard format like [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) or [yaml](/questions/tagged/yaml) for which a parser already exists.

Printing the stack trace is not a very good way of handling an `IOException`.  Such an exception should be considered fatal, not a situation to spew some text and try to continue.  If you don't know what to do with an exception, just declare `throws IOException` to propagate it.

### Parsing

Two of the private methods parse the help file.  Assuming that the file is small, it should be better parse it into a data structure just once at the beginning.

`try(BufferedReader topicReader = new BufferedReader((new FileReader(HELP_SYSTEM_FILE_PATH))))` has an extra pair of parentheses.  It would be better written as

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(HELP_SYSTEM_FILE_PATH);
     BufferedReader topicReader = new BufferedReader(fr);) {
    …
}
```

… both because it keeps the lines shorter and because it would close the `FileReader` properly if the `FileReader` constructor throws an exception.

### Run loop

Your `run()` loop should be better structured to avoid the redundant `isStop()` checks.

```
private void run() {
    // readTopics();    <-- Perhaps better done in the constructor
    System.out.printf("Try the help system. Enter \"%s\" to end.", STOP_WORD);
    for (String topic; !isStop(topic = getSelection()); ) {
        if (!helpOn(topic)) {
            System.out.printf("Topic not found: %s%n", topic);
        }
    }
}
```